# Typescript compiler -disable or remove

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have a Create React App project and I'm using Yarn with React Scripts.

In this is a small Typescript component, that I just compile when I'm working on it.  This has been fine for a year now with no problems.

Recently I upgraded VSCode and now all hell has broken lose and I've lost a few days this week fighting Typescript errrors that stop the application compiling when there were no errors before.

Things like it won't allow modules.export etc.. with the following error:

```
following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.isolatedModules must be true (implementation limitation)
```

I can't even just delete tsconfig.json as it automatically re-adds a new one.

Is there anyway just to stop the Typescript compiler and leave the Typescript alone until I want to work on it again, I have deadlines for other parts of the application and this is driving me insane.

Comment: VS Code will not auto compile your code or auto generate tsconfigs . Do you have an extension that could be causing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include in your [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) configuration file an exclusion rule for that file you're getting errors you don't want to solve.

For example, if the file name is someFile.ts:

```
{
   "exclude": ["someFile.ts", "otherFile.js"],
   // ...rest of the config
}
```